# Trouble Loading Machine Learning Model in Python with TensorFlow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I'm facing issues while trying to import an h5 model in Python using the Keras library. I have a trained model saved in the h5 format, which consists of four files: model.h5.meta, model.h5.index, model.h5.data-00000-of-00001, and checkpoint. However, when I attempt to load the model using the keras.models.load_model() function, it throws an error stating that it can't find the model file.

I have checked the file path and made sure that the model file is present in the specified directory. I have also tried different variations of the file name and path, but the issue persists. I have installed the necessary dependencies and confirmed that I have the required versions of TensorFlow and Keras.

I have followed tutorials and documentation, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm seeking guidance on how to correctly import the h5 model in Python using Keras. Any help or insights into this problem would be greatly appreciated.

I am using python 3.9.16

1. Initially, I attempted to load the h5 model using the `keras.models.load_model()` function with the appropriate file path:

   - Expected: The model should load without any errors.
   - Actual: However, I received an OSError indicating that no file or directory was found at the specified path.
2. I made sure to check the directory where the h5 model is stored and confirmed that it contains the necessary files: model.h5.meta, model.h5.index, model.h5.data-00000-of-00001, and checkpoint.

   - Expected: With the presence of these files, the model should be loadable.
   - Actual: Despite verifying the existence of the files, the loading process continues to fail.
3. I also ensured that all the required dependencies, including TensorFlow and Keras, are installed and up to date.

   - Expected: Having the correct dependencies should enable successful model loading.
   - Actual: Even though the dependencies are properly installed, the error persists.

In addition to the above attempts, I have experimented with different variations of the file path and name but have not found a solution yet. I have consulted documentation and followed tutorials, but I'm still unable to import the h5 model successfully.

Any guidance or insights on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have saved the model weights checkpoint which are saved as checkpoint files `model.h5.meta`, `model.h5.index`, `model.h5.data-00000-of-00001`, `checkpoint`, not the entire model. Hence, using `models.load_model()` to reload these checkpoints is causing the above error. To reload these weight checkpoints you need to use the below code:

```
model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)  #the path of checkpoint files
```

Please refer to this [TF document](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#save_checkpoints_during_training) for more understanding in this.